# jQuery - Show/Hide Image on Expand Collapse Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a simple issue. I have developed some code that collapses and expands to DIV's using the [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/). What i want to now do is show/hide the corresponding expand and collapse images.

**.htmlpage:**

```
<li>
<div class="toggle_head togglebackground">
    &nbsp<img src="images/expand.png" alt="Expand" id="expand" class="expand">
    &nbsp<img src="images/collapse.png" alt="Collapse" id="collapse" class="collapse">
    <label> Cookies</label>
</div>
<div class="box toggle_body">
    <ul class="list">
        <li>
           <label disabled="disabled">Information about cookies.....</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- !END section (Cookies) -->
</li>
<li>
<div class="toggle_head togglebackground">
    &nbsp<img src="images/expand.png" alt="Expand" id="expand" class="expand">
    &nbsp<img src="images/collapse.png" alt="Collapse" id="collapse" class="collapse">
    <label> Terms</label>
</div>
<div class="box toggle_body">
    <ul class="list">
        <li>
           <label disabled="disabled">Information about terms and conditions.....</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- !END section (Terms) -->
</li>
```

jQuery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

//hide the all of the element with class msg_body
$(".toggle_body").hide();
$(".collapse").hide();

//toggle the componenet with class msg_body
$(".toggle_head").click(function()
{
    $(this).next(".toggle_body").slideToggle(300);
    //$(".collapse").show();
    //$(this).next(".collapse").show();

});

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the callback of `slideToggle` to `toggle` the visibility of the expand/collapse elements:

```
$(".toggle_head").click(function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.next(".toggle_body").slideToggle(300, function() {
      $this.children('img').toggle();
    });

});
```

That will toggle the visibility of all images which are direct children of `.toggle_head`.

By the way, it sounds as if you're using the same IDs on multiple elements. Remove them, IDs must be unique.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HHguX/2/)

Comment: your solution works as expected. I'm confused about the IDs however, as far as i can see i haven't reused them, i have with classes however??

Comment: Look at your `<img>` elements, they all have `id="expand"` or `id="collapse"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".toggle_head").click(function()
{
    $(this).next(".toggle_body").slideToggle(300, function () {
        var status = $(this).is(':hidden');
        $('#collapse').toggle(status);
        $('#expand').toggle(!status);
    });
});
```

Not tested, but gives the idea

Answer (score 0):

I've also made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/VHnAM/) for you. The difference is, that it closes already opened "bodies", that's why I use `:visible` there

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle_head").click(function()
    {
        if ($(this).next(".toggle_body").css('display')!=='block') {
            $(".toggle_body:visible").slideToggle(300);
            $(this).next(".toggle_body").slideToggle(300);
            $(this).find('img').toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

and CSS is used instead of `hide()` first

(also it has nice images!)